# Iterating with filter in Angular factory itself

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

My problem is that I use a factory with 2 controller, the first return me a whole array, the secon is wanted to return me only one item, which is based on a filtering expression. I get the last two parameters from the url, iterate through the array and examine which array item has that value for a specific attribute, then only return that element with all of its attributes and values. It is no problem so far, but how to do it in Angular, if I want to filter in the return tree of the declared array itself, inside the factory?
For help, I attach the jsfiddle link, where you can find a little explanation in the html section:
https://jsfiddle.net/65224mk6/

Here is my factory and controllers so far if you don't want to check the link.

```
portApp.factory("workFactory", function() {
    var selected = [];
    var works = [
    {
        Title: "Sprite",
        subTitle: "",
        Link: "sprite",
        Thumbnail: "img/portfolio02.png",
        Image: "img/ismont.png"
    },
    {
        Title: "Pepsi",
        subTitle: "Kristályvíz",
        Link: "pepsi",
        Thumbnail: "img/portfolio03.png",
        Image: "img/sanofimont.png"
    }
    ];
    return {
        list: function() {
            return works;
        },
        selected: function() {
            return works[0]; // probably selected[]
        }
    };
});

portApp.controller("listController", ["$scope", "workFactory", 
    function($scope, workFactory) {
        $scope.allWorks = workFactory.list();
    }
]);

portApp.controller("itemController", ["$scope", "workFactory", "$stateParams",
    function($scope, workFactory, $stateParams) {
        var detPath = $stateParams.itemLink;
        //$scope.selectedWork = workFactory.selected(detPath);
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selected should be a function with one parameter:

```
 return {
   list: function() {
     return works;
   },
   selected: function(detPath) {
     //Filter based on the detPath
     selected = works.filter(function(work) {
       return work.Link == detPath;
     });
     return selected;
   }
 };
```

Then you can call it in the controller:

```
 portApp.controller("itemController", ["$scope", "workFactory", "$stateParams",
   function($scope, workFactory, $stateParams) {
     var detPath = $stateParams.itemLink;
     $scope.selectedWork = workFactory.selected(detPath);
   }
 ]);
```

Comment: Oh thank you, helped me really a lot :) just one question.. after I got returned the $scope.selectedWork.. how can I access to it in my view? Is {{ selectedWork.Title }} should be enough? Just because it didn't get me anything in that way right now.

Comment: selectedWork is now an array. If you want just an object, get the first object of the array in the controller:   $scope.selectedWork = workFactory.selected(detPath)[0];

Comment: In meanwhile I managed to figure it out :) and checked the content with the $scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', function(){ ..., and it gets back the datas I want to see :) Unfortunately in my view, nothing renders :s Here is the view: <div ng-controller="ItemController">
<h1>{{ selectedWork.Title }}</h1><h3 ng-show="selectedWork.subTitle != null">{{ selectedWork.subTitle }}</h3><img src="{{ selectedWork.Image }}"/></div> Maybe mistyped something?